# Get most recent month name with Power BI measure?

Tags: date, powerbi, dax

I have 2 columns, **Status** and **Date**. The "Status" column contains three values ('Past Due', 'Soon Due', 'Calibrated').

I would like to display the **most recent** month name calculated for each of these status categories separately. Specifically, I would like to create a table visual where we have 3 different columns with the names "Past Due", "Soon Due", and "Calibrated". These columns display the most recent month name for dates corresponding to each status category, as outlined in the screenshots below.

**Sample Input:**

[image: Input Table]

**Desired Output:**

[image: Output Table]

Comment: edit your question, add some dummy data and your desired result

Comment: I have already mentioned in screenshot. what output I want to get @msta42a

Comment: You have not added any sample data you are working on. In that case, I can't help. I do not know where you have two lines from, if you write that you want to get Last month name, I would assume that there should be one line.

Comment: @msta42a i edited my question now i hope you will understand.

Answer (score 1):

**FORMAT([DateField], "MMM")** is the key DAX function here.

I've outlined the 3 measures below that should give you the result you want. Replace "Table1" with your table name.

**Past Due**

```
Past Due = CALCULATE(FORMAT(MAX(Table1[Date]), "MMM"), Table1[Status] = "Past Due")
```

**Soon Due**

```
Soon Due = CALCULATE(FORMAT(MAX(Table1[Date]), "MMM"), Table1[Status] = "Soon Due")
```

**Calibrated**

```
Calibrated = CALCULATE(FORMAT(MAX(Table1[Date]), "MMM"), Table1[Status] = "Calibrated")
```

**Measures in Table**

[image: Result Table]

Comment: Glad it helped! If it solved your problem, would you mind marking it as the accepted solution (checkmark next to the answer)?

Comment: FYI, I already marked it as the accepted solution.

Comment: your answer is acceptable but it's not working on my case , My output is returning the same month name in all columns ( Past Due, Soon Due & Calibrated). how is this possible?   My objective was to display Last Month name by each status. Is there any possible way here (in comment section)? where I can attach output screen  for your better understanding. I'm using these columns in table visual ( "EQUIPMENT",  "Equipment Name", "AREA", "CYCLE_PER_UNIT"," Past Due", "Soon Due", "Calibrated")

Comment: I have checked in my data last month is April but these measure display September month name why? I think this measure isn't working correctly

Comment: Could you try attaching a screenshot and sample data to the original question? The “.Month” piece that you added to the solution might have adjusted the output, but I need to see more.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, I do think that the ".Month" piece that you added is causing the odd behavior. When MAX(Table1[Date].Month) table is used in the measure, it gets the max string value among available months (i.e. "September" has the greatest alphabetical order). You should instead use MAX(Table1[Date]) (without the ".Month"). This will get the most recent date, and then the Format(..., "MMM") piece extracts the month from that date. Could you try removing the ".Month" piece and see if that solves the issue?

Comment: Now, scenario is changed. I'm posting new requirement  with new question so, you can comment on that post.